# Is there a shorter way to make a unit converter program in C?

Tags: c

i am making a unit convert program, but my code is too long and just go on forever, here is the first part of my code :

```
int measure;
int from;
int to;
float input;
float output;

printf("Choose measurement :\n1 : Length\n2 : Area\n3 : Temparture\n");
measure = getch();

switch(measure){
    case '1' :
        printf("\nYou want to change from :\n1 : mm\n2 : cm\n3 : dm\n4 : m\n5 : dcm\n6 : hm\n7 : km\n");
        from = getch();
        printf("\nTo : \n1 : mm\n2 : cm\n3 : dm\n4 : m\n5 : dcm\n6 : hm\n7 : km\n");    
        to = getch();

        printf("Enter number : ");   scanf("%f", &input);

        switch(from){
            case '1' :
                switch(to){
                    case '1' : output = input;                printf("%f mm = %f mm", input, output);   break;
                    case '2' : output = input/10;             printf("%f mm = %f cm", input, output);   break;
                    case '3' : output = input/1000;           printf("%f mm = %f dm", input, output);   break;
                    case '4' : output = input/10000;          printf("%f mm = %f m", input, output);   break;
                    case '5' : output = input/100000;         printf("%f mm = %f dcm", input, output);   break;
                    case '6' : output = input/1000000;        printf("%f mm = %f hm", input, output);   break;
                    case '7' : output = input/10000000;       printf("%f mm = %f km", input, output);   break;
                }
                break;

            case '2' :
                 switch(to){
                    case '1' : output = input*10;           printf("%f cm = %f mm", input, output);   break;
                    case '2' : output = input;              printf("%f cm = %f cm", input, output);   break;
                    case '3' : output = input/10;           printf("%f cm = %f dm", input, output);   break;
                    case '4' : output = input/100;          printf("%f cm = %f m", input, output);   break;
                    case '5' : output = input/1000;         printf("%f cm = %f dcm", input, output);   break;
                    case '6' : output = input/10000;        printf("%f cm = %f hm", input, output);   break;
                    case '7' : output = input/100000;       printf("%f cm = %f km", input, output);   break;
                }
                break;
```

and it will go on case 3,4,5, ... until the kilometer, not including the area and the temparture measurement, and other thing i want to add

Is there any shorter way to do this ? Thanks :)

Comment: You should use tables of units and conversion factors.

Comment: If your program works and all you want is a *code review* then you should post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because CodeReview.stackexchange.com is the appropriate place to get design suggestions.

Comment: oh sorry guy, i don't know, i am just a new member in stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

You can do this trivially if you pick an *Intermediate* unit (arbitrarily?) which is the one you use internally. (I always use SI units for that.)

Then your conversions are always of the form

`Input Unit -> Intermediate Unit -> Output Unit`.

Since `Unit -> Intermediate Unit` is the reciprocal of `Intermediate Unit -> Unit` you only need to maintain a single-column table.

Comment: ok i will try :) tks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can remove a lot of this duplication.  Try and see where things repeat unnecessarily and see where they differ.  If you think you can handle the difference programmatically, then you should try it and you may have simplified it a bit further.

I would also recommend you check the inputs the user gives you so you don't suffer from a buffer over/underflow.

**Edit:** removed `fromMeter`; dividing by `toMeter` is the same thing.

```
int fromIdx, toIdx;
char measure, from, to;
float input, output;
char *unit[] = {"mm", "cm", "dm", "m", "dcm", "hm", "km"};
float toMeter[] = {0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000};

printf("Choose measurement :\n1 : Length\n2 : Area\n3 : Temparture\n");
scanf("%c", &measure);

switch(measure){
    case '1' :
        printf("\nYou want to change from :\n1 : mm\n2 : cm\n3 : dm\n4 : m\n5 : dcm\n6 : hm\n7 : km\n");
        scanf(" %c", &from);
        if(from < '1' || from > '7') {
            // invalid choice
            return;
        }
        fromIdx = from - '1';

        printf("\nTo : \n1 : mm\n2 : cm\n3 : dm\n4 : m\n5 : dcm\n6 : hm\n7 : km\n");
        scanf(" %c", &to);
        if(to < '1' || to > '7') {
            // invalid choice
            return;
        }
        toIdx = to - '1';

        printf("Enter number : ");   scanf(" %f", &input);
        output = input * toMeter[fromIdx] / toMeter[toIdx];

        printf("%f %s = %f %s\n", input, unit[fromIdx], output, unit[toIdx]);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `* fromMeter[toIdx];` the same as `/ toMeter[toIdx]`, i.e. you have redundancy in your static data?

Comment: Very true, will update.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Have an upvote!